# plotting graph in sapui5 with pandas dataframe

Tags: sapui5

As pandas supports dataframe to json conversion and the dataframe can be converted to a json data as below: `(1) and 2) are just for references nothing to do with sapui5`,

1) for eg:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['madrid', 10], ['venice', 20],['milan',40],['las vegas',35]],columns=['city', 'temp'])
df.to_json(orient="records")
```

gives:

```
[{"city":"madrid","temp":10},{"city":"venice","temp":20},{"city":"milan","temp":40},{"city":"las vegas","temp":35}]
```

and

```
df.to_json(orient="split")
```

gives:

```
{"columns":["city","temp"],"index":[0,1,2,3],"data":[["madrid",10],["venice",20],["milan",40],["las vegas",35]]}
```

As we have json data , this data could be used as input to plot properties.

2)for the same json data I have created an API (running on localhost):

```
http://127.0.0.1:****/graph
```

API using in flask:(just for refernce)

```
from flask import Flask
import pandas as pd

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/graph')
def plot():
    df=pd.DataFrame([['madrid', 10], ['venice', 20], ['milan', 40], ['las vegas', 35]],
                      columns=['city', 'temp'])
    jsondata=df.to_json(orient='records')
    return jsondata

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

postman result:

```
[
    {
        "city": "madrid",
        "temp": 10
    },
    {
        "city": "venice",
        "temp": 20
    },
    {
        "city": "milan",
        "temp": 40
    },
    {
        "city": "las vegas",
        "temp": 35
    }
]
```

3)How can I make use of this sample api to fetch data and then plot a sample graph for `{city vs temp}` using sapui5 ??

looking for an example to do so, (or) any help on how to make use of api's in sapui5 ?

Comment: Have you looked at the [VizFrame samples](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame)? Try implementing a graph based on those. Then, if you get stuck again, [edit] the question with the code you tried and people will help you correct it. It is a bit hard to know what you need if you don't have a partial solution.

Comment: sure sir definately ,....thanks